# Returning value from a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

When I'm trying to return my res.data from my function and then console.log it I get undefined but if I console.log it from inside the function I get the normal result

```js
const getDefaultState = () => {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/urls/todos")
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data) {
        console.log(res.data);
        return res.data;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};


console.log(getDefaultState());
```

so I get first

> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

(the normal value)
but then from outside I get

> undefined

Comment: You can use async/await

Comment: As @SirwanAfifi suggests it, you get `undefined` because when you console.log(getDefaultState()), your request is still processing. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Comment: Please be aware that `getDefaultState` will never return the "real" value. The best you can do is have it return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the call as well:

```
const getDefaultState = () => {
  return axios.get("http://localhost:5000/urls/todos")
        .then((res) => {
           if (res.data) {
              console.log(res.data);
              return res.data;
           }
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the promise instead.

```
const getDefaultState = () =>
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/urls/todos")
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data) {
        console.log(res.data);
        return res.data;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

That way you can listen to the result outside the function:

```
getDefaultState().then(/* do stuff */);
// or
const res = await getDefaultState();
```

Comment: Bear in mind that since there are cases where you don't return anything inside the 'then' clause and you never return anything in the 'catch' clause, you could still get undefined/null. But as long as the promise resolves correctly and there is data, you will recieve it this way.

Comment: Don't forget async if you want to use await

Comment: You mind want to point out what it is you changed (removed the brackets).